# Cannot read property of undefined in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I wrote a small jade script that is

```
ul.sidebar-nav
  each(record in #{records})
    li
      a(href='#') #{record.sender}
```

I am passing a records array object to the jade template, but getting undefined for `record`. Can anyone please explain why I am getting this error?

Here is the full error:

```
/home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/views/index.jade:9 7| each(record in #{records}) 8| li > 9| a(href='#') #{record.sender} 10| Cannot read property 'sender' of undefined

TypeError: /home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/views/index.jade:9
    7|         each(record in #{records})
    8|           li
  > 9|             a(href='#') #{record.sender}         
    10| 

Cannot read property 'sender' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:216:8), <anonymous>:83:49)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:216:8), <anonymous>:110:22)
    at res (/home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:217:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:360:38)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:350:21)
    at View.render (/home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:93:8)
    at EventEmitter.app.render (/home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:530:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:933:7)
    at /home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/routes/index.js:13:7
    at /home/ritesh/Sample/Sample1/Sample/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:172:16
```

Comment: Try `each record in records`, and mind that records should be an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
  each(record in #{records})
```

You don't want to be parsing `records` here; you just want to use it as an array. Just use

```
  each(record in records)
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
each record in records
```